# How to load and use images in applets?

Tags: java, image, path, applet, relative-path

I've been going at it for 2 days now and I can't find a way how to load images properly. The applet is going to be run locally on a different computer, and it's not in a jar file (for
one previous applet, for the same project, I've only used the .class files and used THEM in directly in the HTML source code). My questions is: how do you load and use images which have a relative path (possibly next to the .class files) ? Here's part of my code

```
try {
    image = null;
    InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream( new FileInputStream( System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\toshiba.jpeg" )); 
    image = ImageIO.read(is); 
    image = image.getScaledInstance(400,200,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH); 
} 
catch (IOException e) {} 
Icon ic = new ImageIcon(image);
```

Comment: *"The applet is going to be run locally on a different computer,.."*  Don't use an applet for that.  Supply the user with an executable Jar with all the resources inside.  Access the resources as an [tag:embedded-resource].  See the [info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for the tag, for a way to form an `URL`.

Comment: 1) Oh.. and applets and files mix like oil and water mix (not).  Use an URL to load the image.  2) Change code of the form `catch (Exception e) { ..` to `catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); // very informative! ..`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **@RoxasShadow** Try to use `getDocumentBase()`. 
>   **@Nick992**  tried it and it returns null, I think I've read somewhere that you can use that only with applets that are accessed on remote websites and not locally.

There is no accounting for what people think.

[image: Where Am I? Applet]

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

// <applet code=WhereAmIApplet width=500 height=50></applet>
public class WhereAmIApplet extends JApplet {

    @Override
    public void init() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1,5,5));
        add(new JLabel("Document Base: " + getDocumentBase()));
        add(new JLabel("Code Base: " + getCodeBase()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `getDocumentBase()`. It returns the path of the folder where the applet is stored.

Comment: tried it and it returns null, I think I've read somewhere that you can use that only with applets that are accessed on remote websites and not locally...
but thanks anyway :)

Comment: Good call on document base, but 'possibly next to the .class files' suggests more the code base.